# How am I leaking memory here, I am freeing temp every time I allocate memory am I not?

Tags: c

A link to the function leaking memory.

```
bool check(const char* word)
{

    uint32_t len = strlen(word);
    char currentWord[len+1];

    for(int k = 0; k <= len; k++)
    {
        currentWord[k] = tolower((char)word[k]);
    }

    bool wordPresent = false;
    uint32_t indexSize = (dict.wordCount / ITEMSPERBUCKET);
    uint32_t index = (hashFunction(currentWord)%(indexSize-1));

    dictNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(dictNode));
    temp = chainedHashTable[index];
    do
    {
        if (strncmp(temp->word, currentWord, temp->len) == 0)
        {
            wordPresent = true;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    while (temp != NULL);

    free(temp);
    return wordPresent;
}
```

http://codepad.org/G8uuS79s

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lose the malloc'd value of `temp` on the very next line after allocating it... you haven't got the value with which to `free()` after that.

Furthermore, when you finally exit your `while` loop and just before calling `free()`, temp == NULL.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome speedy response, worked a charm, and facepalm as soon as I read your solution!

Answer (score 4):

Directly after you `malloc`,

```
dictNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(dictNode));
temp = chainedHashTable[index];
```

you overwrite the address of the `malloc`ed memory with `chainedHashTable[index]`. Thus you lose the only handle to the `malloc` ed memory, and leak that.

Fortunately, what you are freeing

```
while (temp != NULL);

free(temp);
```

is a null pointer, and `free`ing that is harmless. If you tried to `free` `chainedHashTable[index]` for example, that might break your programme.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome speedy response, worked a charm, and facepalm as soon as I read your solution!